# Batch - error in findstr

Tags: batch-file, findstr

My objective is

1. Map a network folder
2. Find a file on per-determined date with specific registration number
3. Copy the file to a specific location

Here is my code:

```
    set "folder="
    set "date="
    set "No="
    set "fileName="
    echo:
    set /p folder=Please enter the folder name
    echo:
    set /p date=Please enter report date yyyymmdd = 
    echo:
    set /p No=Please enter registration number =  
    echo:
    net use Q: \\%folder%\d$\h
    net use R: \\%folder%\d$\p
    CD Q:\%date%\0\ | findstr /i %No% "*.*"
    echo:
    set /p fileName=Paste filename to resend = 
    echo:
    copy %fileName% y:
    echo:
    echo Copy Complete
    echo:
```

Here is the output:

```
Please enter the folder you want to connect/reconnect = 0714
Please enter report date yyyymm = 201407
Please enter registration number =  74471958
The command completed successfully.
The command completed successfully.

FINDSTR: Cannot open NTUSER.DAT
FINDSTR: Cannot open NTUSER.DAT.LOG

Paste filename to resend =
```

I am currently running the batch from **D:** and I have copy **findstr.exe** to the same folder from which the batch file is running.

Currently I am really out of ideas and hope someone can point me on a right directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
CD Q:\%date%\0\ | findstr /i %No% "*.*"
```

The pipe `|` takes the *output* of the previous command and feeds it to the following command.

The output of a `cd`command is empty (or "the system can not find this path").

So this is not, what (I think) you need.

I think, you want to go to `Q:\%date%\0\` and search there for files, that contain `%no%`.

To do this, use:

```
cd /d "Q:\%date%\0\"
findstr /i %No% "*.*"
```

You need the `/d` parameter with `cd` to change to another drive (or use `pushd` instead of `cd`)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with needing `findstr.exe` depends on precisely how you are executing this batch. This executable should be in `c:\windows\system32` and that directory should be in your `path`. I'd `echo %path%` and pursue it from there.

Next problem is `%date%`. This is a magic variable and contians the current date. It can be overridden by a `set` command, but if it's set to *nothing* as you have done in you code, then it will return the current system date in the current user's format.

AFAIAA, `CD` produces no output; it merely changes directory.

I suspect you are using `cygwin` which provides different definitions for some commands.